# Radio button to Enable Disable using Javascript

Tags: javascript, radio-button, dom-events

```
onContextMenu = function (element, layerNo, layerName)
 {
    
    this.conMenu = new ContextMenu(this); 
    this.conMenu.call(this.conMenu, menuManager);
    },
    
    if (KKC.UserInfo.Level == "1"){
        document.getElementById('RB1').enable;
    }
```

I need to create an event where if `UserInfo.Level == 1` admin is logged in, all radio will be enable but if it is `UserInfo.Level == 2`, some of the radio button will be disabled. But I need some help how to make this happen, Can Anyone give me an Idea? I'm just a beginner with Javascript so my knowledge about this is really limited.

Update:

```
 onContextMenu = function (element, layerNo, layerName)
{   
    
    var _rb1 = document.getElementById('RBI');
    var _rb2 = document.getElementById('RB2');
    var _rb3 = document.getElementById('RB3');
    
    this.conMenu = new ContextMenu(this); 
    this.conMenu.call(this.conMenu, menuManager);
    },
    
    if (KKC.UserInfo.Level == "1"){
        this._rb1.enable = true;
        this._rb2.enable = true;
        this._rb3.enable = true;
```

What about like this? Will this work?

Answer (score 0):

For disable:

```
document.getElementById('RB1').disabled = true;
```

For enable:

```
 document.getElementById('RB1').disabled = false;
```